# Matrix: limiting translate and scale in android

Tags: android

I am drawing an image in android using canvas.
I'm using surfaceview's ontouch method to let the user scale and move the image.

I can already limit the scaling but I have a problem limiting the translate.
I can limit translate only if the scale of the matrix is in its original form, but if the
scale is changed I'm having a problem limiting its translation.

Comment: well, its bad news really... how can we help you?

Comment: thanks for replying, i actually need help with limiting the translation when the matrix is being scaled